# CSRF Token generate different one each GET method (Laravel 5.3 server & Ionic 2 client)

Tags: session, ionic2, client-server, laravel-5.3, csrf

I'm making an application with Ionic 2 to login to Laravel 5.3 server. When i **GET** CSRF Token from Postman, I see that the CSRF Token will never change even how many time I **GET** (unless the session is ended). So I can login from Postman when **Post** the Token with username and password. But from my Ionic 2 app, each time I **GET** CSRF Token, the CSRF Token is change to an other one. So the CSRF verification always return error.

[You can see the CSRF Token has been changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbAsX.png)

My **GET** returned CSRF Token from **Laravel** server:

```
Route::get('api/csrf', function() {
    return Session::token();
});
```

My **GET** method I do from **Ionic** app client:

```
token() {
    this._token = this.http.get('http://localhost:8000/api/csrf').map((res:Response) => res.text()).subscribe(data => {
        consoler.log(data);
    });
}
```

I understand that the problem is I didn't save the Token right way or some thing with **session** cookie. If you guys have any idea, please help me! Thank you for read all ask!

p/s: 
  1. My English is not good, so please forgive me if I have some mistake.
  2. I'm developing Cordova app with Ionic (Ionic tabs application, i think so) and API server with Laravel

Comment: Are you developing an API or a web application?

Comment: i'm developing API server and both mobile & web application

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing a RESTful API, **that authenticates via the `Authorization` header**, then you don't need CSRF protection altogether.

CSRF occurs when another website makes a request to yours, and that website happens to be authenticated due to authentication being based on cookies or something similar

When authentication happens to be on an HTTP header, other websites simply can't make forms to do such a request, they don't have enough privileges to add a header to their request, and thus, requests will be unauthenticated and the user will be safe. If you store your authorization token in `localStorage`, then they can't access that either.

So basically, authenticate your API via the `Authorization` header and disable CSRF protection, and then you should be fine.

Comment: yes, i'm working with RESTful API. But when i send a request login to the server, it returned `(1/1) TokenMismatchException
in VerifyCsrfToken.php (line 68)` . I detected that the CSRF Token I **GET** from the server is not the only one. So, I think the problem is the CSRF Token from server is not stored on my app (in some way). I wonder to know how could I store it.

Comment: But if I disable CSRF protection, is My app still private?

Comment: I confirm that I'm developing Cordova app with Ionic (Ionic tabs application, i think so)

Comment: Depends on how you authenticate. If you authenticate using the `Authorization` header, you'll be safe. And for the error, you need to disable the CSRF protection middleware.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to use others way to Authenticate, like `Authorization` as you suggested

Answer (score 0):

Oh I found the solution, it is stupid basic that i forgot: Laravel has API Authentication it own. So all i need to do is use the token from API Authentication instead of normal Authentication with Cookie of CSRF. 
Thanks for read my question! If it bothered you guys, pls forgive me ^^